# Want to use angularjs resource object with action method

Tags: angularjs, action

I want to make a search query to my server with angularjs resource object and i have written such an resource object;

app.factory('EcriDeviceListService', function ($resource) {
    var Url = "http://localhost:60766/api/EcriDeviceLists/:id/:queryText";
    return $resource(Url, { id: '@Id' },{ update: { method: 'PUT' },'search': { method:'GET', {queryText:''}})
    });

with this code i want to make a search query like this;

EcriDeviceListService.search({queryText:'abc'})

http://localhost:60766/api/EcriDeviceLists/queryText=abc"

how should i configure my resource object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should configure `$resource` object like this:

```
$resource('http://localhost:60766/api/EcriDeviceLists/:id/:queryText', { 
        id: '@Id', 
        queryText: '' 
    }, { 
        update: { 
            method: 'PUT' 
        }, 
        search: {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });
```